# Xcode: push notifications to build on device work but not to TestFlight/App Store install on same device

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I've realized that I can test push notifications in development and prod builds on local devices- but they don't work with real installs from TestFlight/App Store.

I think this has to do with Xcode's signing of builds vs. archives, but I cannot figure out what to do to fix my current configuration. I use the Xcode auto signing, FYI.

I use Mixpanel for event tracking and notifications, which also lets me confirm the device token is being retrieved successfully. I have my production push certificate uploaded there.

If I have a build running on my device, I can grab the token from a log message and send a push to it (using my prod push certificate) with a different utility called Pusher- this works perfectly.

However, if I download my app from TestFlight or the App Store, start it, get the resulting token from Mixpanel, and send another notification via Mixpanel, it never shows up. Going back to Pusher, if I attempt a push with the token from Mixpanel, I get an `APN invalid token` error.

Both of these tokens were grabbed the same way- immediately after the user agrees to notifications or the push plugin finishes setup. They were also grabbed on the same code- but one from a running Xcode build, the other from an archive on the TestFlight.

Project setup- I have the Push switch set to on in the Xcode Capabilities menu, and I've generated push certs for dev and production (well, 2 for prod by accident. I figured it was fine):

[image: certs]

I also have the Distribution and Dev provisioning profiles created. This is where my question lies- I read that Xcode doesn't use the Distribution profile you create until archiving, and uses it's own until then if you have Automatic Signing selected in the code signing settings.

Is that why I have 2 profiles here? The one I created shows as Active & also lists Push Notifications under services if I expand the entry below:

[image: provisioning profiles]

The cert my production provisioning profile is signed with is an iOS Distribution certificate that matches the team I have selected for signing:

[image: signing info]

While writing this up I realized that maybe my release build settings, specifically signing, were wrong. I though they should also be using my `Iphone Distribution: MyCompany Inc (USA)` certificate (instead of the default `iOS Developer` identity), since my Distribution provisioning profile is signed with that same certificate. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either.

If my build settings look like this (or if I select the generic `iOS Distribution` from the dropdown for Release identity):

[image: build settings]

I can't actually build- I get an error that there are conflicting provisioning settings. If I use the `iPhone Distribution: MyCompany Inc (USA)` certificate just in the `Release` line (not the `Any iOS SDK` line), I can create an archive, but I see the same behavior.

I thought for sure this was it, since I've been using my MyCompany Inc (USA) development team for provisioning when validating/uploading archives.

I also tried turning off automatic signing and setting the debug and release profiles to the dev and prod provisioning profiles I made in the Apple Developer site. No luck there either.

Just to come full circle- this is the archive summary information I see when using automatic signing:

[image: archive info]

This is correct, right? The identity listed was used to sign the selected provisioning profile, so that should be all I need as far as proper signing, right? Given the other setup, of course.

I'm completely stumped at this point- how am I supposed to configure signing for archives?

Answer (score 0):

This didn't end up being a signing issue after all- while I'm still a little bewildered on exactly what I need to do for signing release builds, it seems the Xcode automatic process handles it properly, given that the correct provisioning profile has been created in your Apple Developer account.

There were 2 issues here:

1. The Pusher utility I was using to send pushes to test devices has an option called "Should use sandbox environment" that's checked by default. Once I unchecked it, I could send pushes to devices that had downloaded TestFlight/App Store builds. I didn't realize the production push certificate could be used both ways.
2. At the same time, I was still having issues sending notifications from Mixpanel. It turns out that, for some reason, some of the devices I try to push to (even with Pusher) don't seem to get a notification with a certain priority level. By adding `"priority": 10` to the custom data of a Mixpanel test notification, I am able to successfully send/receive them. I figured this out by playing with the dropdown in the screenshot of Pusher below:

[image]

My own device would receive pushes with any of these 3 levels selected, but other devices would only receive pushes with the "Immediately" level or "Priority: None" level selected. Why? I have no idea.